# Distinct values from array based on a part of the string in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following array:

```
var array= [
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
  'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
]
```

I would like to distinct this array to return just with:

```
//['http://www.example.com/page1','http://www.example.com/page2']
```

How would I do this with JS?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a free coding service. (those methods may help: `String.prototype.split()`, `Array.prototype.map()`, `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `new Set()`)

Comment: Have you tried something ? It looks like you need to remove the URLs hash and keep only the unique ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slice` the base url and then use `includes`.

```js
var array = [
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
  'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
];


const output = [];

array.forEach((url) => {
  const base = url.slice(0, 28);
  if (!output.includes(base)) output.push(base);
});

console.log(output);
```

-- Edit--

```js
var array = [
    'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
    'http://www.example.com/page123/#comment-98733',
    'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
    'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
  ];
  
  
  const output = [];
  
  array.forEach((url) => {
    const idx = url.lastIndexOf('/');
    const base = url.slice(0, idx);
    if (!output.includes(base)) output.push(base);
  });
  
  console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply? Something like this, but what if the `example.com/page1` has different length? like: `example.com/how-to-dinstinct-values-from-array-based-on-a-part-of-the-string/#comment98733`

Comment: @spaceman - See edit. use `lastIndexOf` to find the `/`. `indexOf('#')` would also work.

Comment: Thank you @randomSoul ! This answer was chosen as the correct one because you can use it with different strings after the last `/`

Answer (score 1):

You should use reduce method of array in javascript, like this

```js
var array = [
    'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
    'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
    'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
    'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
]

const newArr = array.reduce((newArray, value) => {
    const url = value.replace(/\/#.*$/, "")
    if (newArray.indexOf(url) === -1) {
        newArray.push(url)
    }
    return newArray;
}, []);

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Set()` to get rid of duplicate elements in an array.

First step, create an array consisting of the URLs without the hashbangs. I'm using `split` for this.

```
const URLs = array.map(URL => URL.split('/#')[0]);
```

You can remove duplicates from that by passing it into a set, then spreading the result back into an array.

```
const uniques = [...new Set(URLs)];
```

Lastly, if you want a more robust method to get the part before the hashbang (e.g. if some URLs contain https), look into using URL. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

```js
const array= [
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
  'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
];

const URLs = array.map(URL => URL.split('/#')[0]);
const uniques = [...new Set(URLs)];

console.log(uniques);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array= [
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
  'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
];

var results = array.map(function(url){
  var index = url.indexOf("#");
  return url.substr(0, index);
});

var disctinctResult = [...new Set(results)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL objects to remove the hashes and then, filter out the duplicates. Here is an example:

```js
const array = [
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
  'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
];

const result = array.map(str => {
  const url = new URL(str);
  return `${url.origin}${url.pathname}`
}).filter((urlStr, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(urlStr) !== index);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can also use regular expressions, to remove unwanted part of string.

```
var array= [
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-1234',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-98733',
  'http://www.example.com/page1/#comment-4298312',
  'http://www.example.com/page2/#comment-2143'
]

const mapped = array.map(item => item.replace(/\/\#comment-[0-9]{0,}/, ''))

console.log(mapped); 
// ["http://www.example.com/page1", "http://www.example.com/page1", 
// "http://www.example.com/page1", "http://www.example.com/page2"]
```